# Live search query using JS and PHP for QA forum

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a QA forum using PHP and MYSQL. Now, I am creating an ask a question page like StackOverflow.
In the input box when I enter a value then I get many related questions title from the database.
This is working but not exact.

Let's start from the database -
I have a QA posts table with columns like - `title, slug, content, tags another category table`.

My HTML Input box form with JQUERY -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStates(value) {
    $.post("search.php", {keywords:value},function(data){
        $("#results").html(data);
    }
    ); 
}
</script>
</head>
<center><input type="text" onkeyup="getStates(this.value)"/></center>
<br>
<center><div id="results"></div></center>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And my PHP code  - search.php

```
 <?php
            $dbc=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test") or die(mysqli_connect_errno());
            $keywords = $_POST["keywords"]; 
        $words = explode(" ",$keywords);
            
            foreach ($words as $keywords) { 
                echo $keywords.'<br>';
                $sql="SELECT * FROM qa_posts WHERE title like '%".$keywords."%' OR content like '%".$keywords."%' OR tags like
    '%".$keywords."%' limit 10 "; 
             
            }
                $q=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
             while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
                echo "<a href='".$res['slug']."'>".$res['title']."</a><br>";
                } 
            ?>
```

As you can see, I have exploded every word from the string.
I am getting question titles. like this -
string ="[image]

but if give space for the next word, it starts from the beginning row of the question rather than searched words (It gives me the beginning row question title after giving space )-

[image]

How can I set that the searched question titles will be displayed related to keywords not from the beginning row of the table if I give space after any word? You can check the images above.

I have spent a full day on it.
Is this ok way or not?
I want searching like stackoverflow  -
[image]
Reference for other ways like StackOverflow or searching methods.

[image]

Comment: Your are foreach-ing over all of your keywords, and create an SQL query in string form each time - but you only _execute_ the query after the loop, so effectively, you are only searching for the _last_ keyword.

Comment: This should rather not be done by firing off a separate query for each keyword in the first place, but by executing _one_ query, that contains a WHERE clause to look for all the terms in one go.

Comment: And of course, as usual, this is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Do you have any other method to find out better results related to keywords in a sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Try and Trim the words to remove whitespaces

```
foreach ($words as $keywords) { 
  echo $keywords.'<br>';
  $keyword = trim($keywords);
  if(strlen($keyword)>0){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM qa_posts WHERE title like '%".$keywords."%' OR content like '%".$keywords."%' OR tags like
    '%".$keywords."%' limit 10 "; 

  $q=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
  while($res=mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
   echo "<a href='".$res['slug']."'>".$res['title']."</a><br>";
  } 
 }
}
```

Comment: How to get the last keyword-related title to come at the first line?